# Make a Single Capturing Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, capture, multiple-instances, single-instance

This is obviously a toy example, but lets say I have a *n* functions like this:

```
void one(const int param) {
    const auto func = [=](){ return 13 == param; };
}

void two(const int param) {
    const auto func = [=](){ return 13 == param; };
}
```

And so on; they all have an identical capturing lambda. Is it possible to have 1 instance of the lambda which always captures the `param` of the function that it is in, rather than *n* instances? Maybe as a follow up question I should be asking, will the compiler already recognize the replication and simplify these to a single instance?

Comment: I don't know if a compiler can optimize this away, but if you need to reuse a function a lot, wouldn't it make sense to just name it and use it normally? Anonymous functions make sense as one offs, not multiple usage entities.

Comment: @kabanus I need it to be a capture :( The functor is being passed as a parameter to a function that I do not own. Thus it has to match the form: `functional<bool()>`

Comment: Well, there's one use case I did not think of. In your example, are `one, two ...` functions you control, and then you would call an `otherNotOwnedFunc(func)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you will get multiple types with this solution.  [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.closure) states that

> The type of a *lambda-expression* (which is also the type of the closure object) is a **unique**, unnamed non-union class type, called the closure type, whose properties are described below.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So each

```
const auto func = [=](){ return 13 == param; };
```

is its own expression so you get a new unique type, even though they are syntactically the same.

What you could do is is factor the repetition out into a functor and then you would only have one class that is defined.

```
class compare
{
    int val;
public:
    compare(int val) : val(val) {}
    bool operator() const { return val = 13; }
};
```

and then your functions would become

```
void one(const int param) {
    const auto func = compare{param};
}

void two(const int param) {
    const auto func = compare{param};
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's the _type_ of the lambda that's unique.  The compiler could still be clever enough to merge the two function bodies (not that I believe for one second that it would).

Comment: @PaulSanders The compiler, or more probably the linker could do that.  Like you I wouldn't bet on it and it is trivial to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply make a function that returns the lambda:

```
auto make_lambda(int param) {
    return [=](){ return 13 == param; };
}

bool one(const int param) {
    return make_lambda(param)();
}

bool two(const int param) {
    return make_lambda(param)();
}
```

The two functions will use the same generated class (not the same instance of it, though). This is the generated code (Obtained using [C++ Insights](https://cppinsights.io/)):

```
__lambda_2_12 make_lambda(int param)
{

  class __lambda_2_12
  {
    public: inline /*constexpr */ bool operator()() const
    {
      return 13 == param;
    }

    private:
    int param;

    public: __lambda_2_12(int _param)
    : param{_param}
    {}

  } __lambda_2_12{param};

  return __lambda_2_12;
}


bool one(const int param)
{
  return make_lambda(param).operator()();
}


bool two(const int param)
{
  return make_lambda(param).operator()();
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer +1. I had a hard time choosing between this and [Nathan Oliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52545147/2642059). In the end I took @NathanOliver's because his is also able to support lambdas that capture by reference.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks! BTW, you can [use references as usual](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00b2e20b0072ab0a) with this. The same caveats about dangling references apply. (The reference is valid as long as the original object is in scope)

Answer (score 3):

The synthetized closure type for a lambda is unique and is defined in the point of definition as stated in `[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/2`:

> The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression [...]

and the capture of the function parameter is used to create a non-static data member fo the **unique** closure type introduced in the scope of the function: `[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/10.2`:

> For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members is unspecified [...]

every introduced closure type will be different and their members depends on what is captured at the moment of definition.

Answer (score 1):

You will always get distinct *types*, but you may not get distinct *code* for each use. This is a job for the linker. The MSVC linker, as well as the experimental `gold` linker, perform what MSVC calls "COMDAT folding" (I don't know what gold calls it), which identifies identical functions within and between translation units and merges them into one.

Comment: I'm curious about this behavior: Shouldn't it be non-conformant? I mean, it should be guaranteed that different functions (even if their implementations are identical) have different addresses. If they are merged into one that obviously doesn't happen.

Comment: No; the unique address guarantee applies to objects, not to functions. The closures of the lambdas will have unique addresses, of course (even between invocations of the same lambda-returning function), but the executable code backing their `operator()`s need not be distinct.